# Write numbers from 1 to 10, set cursor position to the beginning and restart the writing

Tags: c#, console, cursor-position

I just came to a strange behavior which I can't explain. I have a console application that writes numbers from 1 to 9 and then sets the cursor to the beginning of the console window again. After that, the loop goes on and restarts writing the numbers from 1 to 10. The problem is that the numbers written before get overwritten instead of moved forward.

My code for better understanding:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
{
    foreach (int number in numbers)
    {
        Console.Write(number + " ");
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
}
```

When I add the line `Console.Write("Test");` below `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);`, I get the following output:

> Test1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

What I didn't expect: When adding `Console.Write(1);` below, I get

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

With my code I wanted to achieve the following:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 [now setting cursor position to the beginning and moving the consisting numbers forward] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 [and so on]

Why isn't the program behaving like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously when you set the cursor of the console to 0,0 you will start overwriting previous values, because of that this happen. You can do this easily with strings concatenation, but I advice you to use `StringBuilder` because it is muttable.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
        {
            StringBuilder numberBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int number in numbers)
            {
                numberBuilder.Append(number + " ");
            }

            sb.Insert(0, numberBuilder.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Here [**dotnet fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oBNYOz) example

Comment: But why is the text "Test" written before the numbers? It obviously isn't overwriting the first two numbers.

Comment: @diiN_ When you specify Test under SetCursor you are going on the beginning of the console and start writing after that on next execution of the for loop you start writing the numbers after test because the location of cursor is 0,4. You can add Thread.Sleep(500) and you will see it better. On last execution of counter loop you are overwriting the test again on first position and you are leaving the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The console is like a canvas, once something is written to it the text is "painted on" till something paints over it or erases it.

When you move the cursor to the start you start overwriting the old text, letter by letter. See this example

```
Console.Write("This is some long text");
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Console.Write("z");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

You can see the text written over slowly, one letter per second.

To get the effect you are looking for you need to keep a buffer in memory of the entire string and edit that string buffer, after you update the buffer you have to write out the entire line again. A easy way to to this is using a `StringBuilder` to act as the buffer (UPDATE: See [mybirthname's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40531017/80274) for example usage)